# What Infomation is collected by a Google Form

Tags: google-forms

I have a question about what information will Google Forms collec.
Will the form creator ever know who fills the form (the Google Account that the user is logging in) ?

Answer (score 1):

They can choose to collect this information, but the form will display a message.

> If you use Google Apps, you can record the email addresses of the
>   people who fill out your form. To do this, select the checkbox next to
>   'Automatically collect respondent's yourdomain.com username' when you
>   create the form. Recipients of your survey will see a message at the
>   top of the form explaining that their username will be collected
>   automatically.

Source: [Additional forms options for Google Apps users](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/160166?hl=en)